# How to get the week number from a date string with 2 character output

Tags: java, scala, simpledateformat

I can use the below code to get the output as *weekNumber: Int = 1* . But my use case require the output as 
*weekNumber: String= **01***. What should be the best efficient way to do approach this?

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields
import java.util.Locale
import java.time.LocalDate

var dateRangeFrom = "20200101"
var date :java.time.LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(dateRangeFrom,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"))

var weekFields :WeekFields =  WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
var weekNumber :Int = date.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
```

*Output - weekNumber: Int = 1*

Comment: Have a look at `String.format`.

Comment: output where? In a string?

Comment: @jhamon - yes preferably in string format.

Comment: As an aside you don’t need to write your own format pattern string for parsing a string like `20200101`. The built-in `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` can do that.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ole. That is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateTimeFormatter with the pattern `ww`:

```
var weekFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ww");
var weekNumber = weekFormat.format(date);
```

"w" is the week of year, "ww" is week of year with two digits (zero fill). You can see the list of formatting codes in the API documentation.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: I find it worth explaining that the one-arg `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()` gives us a formatter with the default locale of the JVM. This means that it uses the week numbering scheme of this locale, just as the code in the question does, so I expect this to be the desired. For example, if my `date` is 2021-01-01 and I run this code in France, I will get `53`. In the US I get `01` instead.